# Check if value in controls was changed from the orginal data on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page with different controls (checkboxes,textareas, ddls..etc), On pageload the data is loaded into controls.

What would be a good approach to check if the data was modified from the original data after the button was clicked. Using c#.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you want to know the appropriate event in the life cycle? Appropriate what?

Comment: sorry spelling mistake, meant to write: good approach

Comment: @Ben you can try with viewstate or hidden input

Answer (score 2):

Hide the default content of controls in HiddenField. Check the last content of controls with comparing the values in hidden fields in ButtonClicked event.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ViewState["Key"]`

try with

**1. In the load**

```
ViewState["Key"] = texbox.Text;
```

**2. Compare in the post the two values**

Comment: I have 20 fields, so you saying to add 20 viewstate parameters and check each one on button click if it was changed?

Answer (score 1):

If this is a web application I would look at Session Variables ,ViewState,etc which I personally prefer Session Variables
If this is a Windows I would look at Properties there are a couple of ways you could do it.
can you provide and example as to what type of data you are wanting to hold 
sounds like you are looking at creating something like a DELTA

Comment: this is a web app, I can use session variables, I have 20 fields, so you saying to check each field and compare to the session variable and see if it was changed?

Comment: Session is an Object so you could lookup the Session.Add Method or you could create a HashFields too

Answer (score 1):

You can inherit from these controls and create `custom controls`. There you can create property to store your initial value. Later you can compare it to the current value and see if it is changed or not.

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing this to check for concurrency? If so, I would recommend using the entity data model. It has built in features to check if a field has changed from the original. Here is a quick example how to use it:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: this is using mvc, i am using web app, can this be done in web app project?

Comment: When you say "web app," do you mean "web forms". If so, then yes, entity framework is agnositic about MVC or Web Forms. Here is the same example in web forms: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef/the-entity-framework-and-aspnet-getting-started-part-1

Comment: ..edit > this is the web forms tutorial on concurrency: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/continuing-with-ef/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-web-application